# Twilio SMS Error - Status 401, Code 20003 - Postman

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to send SMS using Twilio from my PHP code and Postman but it always returns the error below.
I confirm everything is correctly set and everything was working months ago.

1. SID and TOKEN are correct and verified 5 times
2. Auth method is correct and the error persists also via test on
   Postman
3. The query is correct and it is the same as the test SMS sent from
   the Twilio console

Error:

```
{
"code": 20003,
"message": "Authenticate",
"more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
"status": 401
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not much knowledgeable about Twillio API but looking at your postman it looks correct the only issue might be with the credentials.

Looking at the error message which leads to a documentation, did you have a look at that?

If you are using a token for auth why are you using Basic auth credentials? this might be the issue

Comment: Hi and thanks. I checked them multiple times and they are correct. Basic auth is the correct way. The Twilio dashboard itself do the same, and the SMS is sent correctly:  https://schiocco.com/shared/2023-12-10_142954.jpg

Comment: If you have not got it figured out, try this way:

copy the complete curl command as you have shown in the above pic and paste it in postman and send it. If its works compare and see what was the mistake.

hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the account sid used for Basic Auth is different from the one shown in the URL. Try to align the two of them and it should work.